# What means mysql "serverStatus: 34" in response of waterline orm in sails.js?

Tags: mysql, sails.js, waterline

Sails.js version 0.12.13.

```
User.query(`CALL someProc()`, function(err, data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

Response:

```
data: OkPacket {
    fieldCount: 0,
    affectedRows: 0,
    insertId: 0,
    serverStatus: 32,
    warningCount: 0,
    message: '',
    protocol41: true,
    changedRows: 0 
}
```

What means "serverStatus: 32"?
And what means "serverStatus: 34"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response from a `.query` call in Sails comes directly from the driver, in this case [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql).  The `serverStatus` is a bitfield.  You can get the list of constants in the [MySQL source code docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/mysql__com_8h.html#a1d854e841086925be1883e4d7b4e8cad) -- the first one in the list represents a value of `1`, the next `2`, then `4`, etc.

So `serverStatus: 32` means that only the sixth bit is set, corresponding to `SERVER_STATUS_CURSOR_EXISTS`:

> The server was able to fulfill the clients request and opened a read-only non-scrollable cursor for a query.
>
> This flag comes in reply to COM_STMT_EXECUTE and COM_STMT_FETCH commands. Used by Binary Protocol Resultset to signal that COM_STMT_FETCH must be used to fetch the row-data.

If you see `serverStatus: 34`, it means both the above *and* the second bit, `SERVER_STATUS_AUTOCOMMIT`, was set:

> Server in auto_commit mode.

Comment: @OsaguiAghedo The values shown on the status flag documentation page are hexadecial valus. A `serverStatus: 34` means `0x22` in hex, which means `SERVER_STATUS_AUTOCOMMIT` (0x02) and `SERVER_STATUS_NO_INDEX_USED` (0x20)  (in [MySQL 14.1.3.4](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/status-flags.html) )